# Does a database connection survive a function call (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have some code like this mock example

```
function openDatabaseConnection() {
  $pdo = new PDO();
}

openDatabaseConnection();

while (true) {
  // is there still an open database connection?
}
```

Php and mysql will close the connection to any open database connections at the end of the script, but is a connection to the database maintained until the end of the script when the database connection is scoped to a function? During the `while (true) {}` section of the code, is there still a db connection? Is it possible that php is maintaining the pointer to the DB variable as a permanent resource internally?

Comment: $pdo is a function variable, it does not exist outside the function openDatabaseConnection

Comment: Are you looking for PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT attribute? This comes with it's own set of conditions. Ebven with this your $pdo connection will be lost.

Comment: Are you looking for some session handler? or what do you exactly mean by permanent resource?

Comment: I meant some sort of reference to the variable so the database connection might be maintained even though it can't be accessed anymore after the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this could be closed with variable scope, I wanted to explain it a bit more for this instance.

As the `$pdo` is declared inside the function, as soon as the function finishes, the variable will be un-referenced.  This allows PHP to close the connection as it's no longer used.

If instead you return the connection and store this return value, this returned value is then available for use further down the script...

```
function openDatabaseConnection() {
  $pdo = new PDO();
  // Configure PDO attributes
  return $pdo;
}

$pdo = openDatabaseConnection();

while (true) {
  // use $pdo for database access
}
```

One thing to mention is that this is more about the variable scope and not the actual connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering - this is what I was looking for. I can see why it might be a question about scope. I know that I did not have access to the database variable without returning it, but I didnt know if the database connection was actually closed as a result. I was worred that php might maintain some sort of internal reference to the DB connection inadvertantly causing it to be maintained even though the variable is inaccessible. Knowing that it is de-referenced internally is what I wanted to know.